# Trying to clear an error prompt using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to clear an error icon on keydown.

** EDIT - adding the HTML **

```
<input class="validate" type="text" data-type="string" id="address" />
<input class="validate" type="text" data-type="number" id="zip" />
```

** END EDIT - Unsure if this will help shed some light **

Currently, the error displays using this function:

```
function validateFields(){

$(".validate").blur(function(){
    var status = "";
    var label = this.id;
    var value = this.value;

    if(value != ""){
        status = "good";
        console.log("status " + status);
    }
    else{
        status = "error";
        console.log("status " + status);
    }

    if(status == "good"){
        label.html(label.html()+' &#9989;');
    }
    if(status == "error"){
        label.html(label.html()+' &#10060;');
    }
  });
}
```

If status equals Error, show the error icon.

So now, I want to clear the error when the user keydowns.  Here is my attempt:

```
function clearError(){
$(".validate").keydown(function(){

    var datatype = $(this).data("type");
    var label = this.id;

    label.html(label.html()+' ');
  });
}
```

Obviously, I am not having much success clearing the error using the above keydown function.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Side note: `$(this).attr('id')` should just be `this.id`

Comment: Also, there are quite a few unused variables in that `clearError` method.

Comment: And then, two more things.  `status` is being set to "good", and never changed.  So, the `if` is pointless.  And then you are setting the value of the label html, to what the label html is.  Effectively, `var x = x + ' ';`  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Taplar - updated. Any thoughts on how to clear the error?

Comment: So is your "error" the `&#...` part?

Comment: @Taplar - yes sir, it is.

Comment: Then what I would suggest is to put a span around the error so that your markup is like `<label>Whatever this is <span class="error"></span></label>`, in which case the setting and removal of the error should target just the span and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The label business with trying to keep the text inside is not very intuitive, so I added span to your label so you remove and add error symbols from the `span` in your functions. Additionally, you had some unnecessary code that could be removed in both functions. For example, your `if` statements checking status were unnecessary since you already checked if the value was empty (where you set the status), therefore you could move that code into the `if` statement checking for empty values.

We set each corresponding `span`'s id to the id of the input with "Span" `id="testSpan"`, so it can be easily accessible by the JS functions. Remember inside jQuery functions `this` always refers to the non-jQuery object, so you can use the JS vanilla methods on it.

This is what I could come up with:

```js
$(".validate").blur(function () {
  var id = this.id; // get id

  if (this.value != "") { // check if input is empty
    document.getElementById(id + "Span").innerHTML = '&#9989;'; //set ok symbol
    console.log("good");
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id + "Span").innerHTML = '&#10060;'; // set error symbol
    console.log("error empty text");
  }
});

$(".validate").keydown(function () {
  // if value is empty set error symbol, otherwise nothing (keep ok symbol)
  if (this.value === "") document.getElementById(this.id + "Span").textContent = "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="test">test<span id="testSpan"></span></label>
<input id="test" class="validate">

<label for="test2">test<span id="test2Span"></span></label>
<input id="test2" class="validate">
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Comment: You got the right id? Usually mean the element does not exist with the id. Might have to edit question and put your code.

Comment: @JohnBeasley did this help or no?